# Degrees of Separation Graph Theoretic Puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There are $n > 3$ people in a country, who have never met each other. We say that the degree of separation between $a$ and $b$ is $n$ if $a$ has met a person who has met a person $\dots$ $n-1$ times who has met $b$. For example, if $a$ has met $b$ and $b$ has met $c$, but $a$ and $c$ have not met, then their degree of separation is $2$. It is $1$ for $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$. If there are multiple such values of $n$, we consider the minimum. We say that the degree of separation is $0$ for $(a,b)$ if there is no such way to link them. Two and only two people can participate in a meeting. What is the minimum number of meetings required such that the degree of separation between any pair is a nonzero number?

I have shown that $2n - 4$ meetings suffices. It is simple to do this via induction. Suppose it is true for $n$ people. Our first meeting is with the $(n+1)$-th person and anyone from the first $n$ people. Then we proceed with the $2n - 4$ meetings and then someone from this group meets with the $(n+1)$-th person. Since $4$ meetings are valid for $4$ people, this holds true for all $n$. How do I show that it could (not) be lower?

Comment: What about just having a talk to b, b talk to c, c talk to d, etc. how many such meetings are there then? Any graph structure which is a tree will suffice. You can also use a simple counting argument to show that any fewer meetings necessarily excludes someone.

Comment: If you look up any $\color{red}{\text{tree}}$... you will find the answer.

Comment: A tree would require 2n - 3 meetings. This process is slightly more optimal.

Comment: A tree only requires $n-1$ meetings.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be the graph on $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ where there is an edge between $a$ and $b$ iff $a$ and $b$ have met each other directly. Then the total number of meetings is the total number of edges in $G$, and the degree of separation between $i$ and $j$; $i,j$ distinct,is finite and positive iff $i$ and $j$ are in the same connected component of $G$. Thus, the number of meetings needed so that the degree of separation between any two pairs $i$ and $j$ is finite and positive is precisely the minimum number of edges a graph on $n$ vertices needs to have to be connected. The number of such edges is $n-1$ and is achieved when $G$ is a tree. [I am assuming here that you are allowed to use that the minimum number of edges a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices needs to be connected is $n-1$, and that any tree on $n$ vertices has precisely $n-1$ edges and so achieves this bound.]

For example, 1 and 2 meet then 2 and 3 meet then 3 and 4 meet, and so on and so forth, $i$ and $i+1$ meet for each $i=1,2, \ldots, n-1$. This is $n-1$ meetings total, and the degree of separation between $i$ and $j$; $i \not = j$; is $|j-i|$.

Another example is $n$ meets with $1, \ldots, n-1$. Then the degree of separation between $i$ and $j$; $i \not = j$,

1. is 1 iff either $i$ or $j$ is $n$, and
2. is 2 iff neither $i$ nor $j$ is $n$.

---

Meanwhile $2n-4$ meetings are necessary and sufficient, for $n \ge 4$, for the *gossip problem*: Each person $1,\ldots, n$ has a unique bit of information and each person $a$ shares whatever he knows to $b$ and vice versa [including whatever each of $a$ and $b$ learned from previous meetings] when $a$ and $b$ meet. Then give a precise lower bound on the number of meetings needed so that everyone knows everyone else's information.

This is significantly more challenging to establish however.